# How do I change an app's status from active to background?

Tags: react-native

So, I have a react-native app, and I want to implement the functionality, that when I press on a button, the app will be hidden (goes in background). I found on facebook's github AppState, but it just shows the app's status, but I need to change it, what should I use instead?

Comment: possible copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801664/how-do-i-exit-shut-down-a-react-native-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You can close app if the user clicks the back button!