# Without forcibly close can not reopen app problem in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

When I exit from apps using `BackHandler.exitApp()` then I exit from apps successfully. But again I am trying to open apps without forcibly close then apps doesn't open from splash screen it is opening from last exit page. Every time I am closing apps forcibly. This problem also happening in APK.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exit/shut down a React Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801664/how-do-i-exit-shut-down-a-react-native-app)

Answer (score 0):

for now react-native doesn't provide any function to exit the app completely but your native android has the capability to do the complete termination. Use the wrapper for react native

here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app this will solve yor issue i guess

Comment: Is this package support `expo` ?

Comment: sorry I have no idea about the expo, may b you can add third-party package

Comment: afaik it won't work for expo since you have to link the bridged functionality and the expo binary is already built.

Comment: @peterp  then what would be the solution of this issue?

Comment: you need to eject the code into a CLI project of react-native to use the third party packages but you need to config the modules that expo already have like navigation map svg etc. @SuryaSingh